# Why does my published Windows Form app have two database files included?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

Everything works as expect in my published WinForms app, but for some reason it includes two database files (.sdf) in the publish folder. Is there a reason for this?

The two files are located in the publish file as:

> APP_DATA/Films_Data.sdf.deploy
>   bin/debug/APP_DATA/Films_Data.sdf.deploy

This is the connection string i am using with a private installation of SQL-CE:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Films_v1.Properties.Settings.Films_DataConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\APP_DATA\Films_Data.sdf"
        providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Any thoughts?